# Specify gradle version based on Android Studio version

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am on Android Studio 1.3 which I believe requires gradle version 1.2 and up. Some of my team can't update yet and so need to use a lower gradle version. Is there an easy way to do that in the same build script? Something like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        if (Android Studio Version <= 1.2 )
        {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
        }
        else
        {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not a question of Android Studio Version if you ask me, what bothers upgrading all to gradle 1.2+?! else you would not expect errors your mates do, because gradle deps are different